# lowpass filtering accelerometer data in android

Tags: android, accelerometer

Hi i am trying to use low pass filter on the accelerometer data which will be used further to update the position of the object. Initially i am storing the accelerometer data in an arraylist namely sensordata. Then with the retrieved accelerometer data i perform some simple math calculation and the result will be stored in accelsum arraylist. With the results in accelsum i would like to perform low pass filtering and store it in lowpassvals arraylist and accordingly i have implemented the low pass filtering method.

**Now the question is when i print the arraylist namely lowpassvals values the output is an emptylist.**  Can someone help me with this. thanks.

**Below is the code**

```
    /*Implemented to do some action upon sensor changed*/
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {


            gyro_x = event.values[0];
            gyro_y = event.values[1];
            gyro_z = event.values[2];


        } else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

            double x = event.values[0];
            double y = event.values[1];
            double z = event.values[2];
            long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
            AccelData data = new AccelData(timestamp, x, y, z);
            sensorData = new ArrayList();
            sensorData.add(data);//sensordata arraylist contains the x,y,z values of accelerometer

            for(int k=0;k<sensorData.size();k++){
                accelsum.add((float) data.sum(x, y, z));//accelsum arraylist contains the power of x,y and z accelerometer values
                for (int i = 0; i < accelsum.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("sum: " + accelsum.get(i));


                }
                for (int i = 0; accelsum.size() > 10; i++) {
                    lowPassVals = lowPass(accelsum, lowPassVals);

                }
                for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                    System.out.println("lowpassvals: " +lowPassVals);
                }

            }
}
    }

    protected List<Float> lowPass(List<Float> input, List<Float> output) {

        for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
            if (output.isEmpty()) {
                return input;
            }
            output.set(i, output.get(i) + ALPHA * (input.get(i) - output.get(i)));


        }
        return output;
    }
```

**This is the acceldata class that handles the accelerometer data.**

```
public class AccelData {
    private long timestamp;
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private double z;

    /*  public AccelData(SensorEvent event) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;

        this.x=event.values[0];
        this.y=event.values[1];
        this.z=event.values[2];
        this.timestamp=event.timestamp;

    }*/

    public AccelData(long timestamp, double x, double y, double z) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;

    }

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(double x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getZ() {
        return z;
    }

    public void setZ(double z) {
        this.z = z;
    }

    public double sum(double x,double y,double z){
        double acc_x=Math.pow(x,2);
        double acc_y=Math.pow(y,2);
        double acc_z=Math.pow(z,2);
        double accsum = acc_x+acc_y+acc_z;
        return accsum;

    }

    public String toString() {

        return "t="+timestamp+", x="+x+", y="+y+", z="+z;
    }
}






    }
```

Comment: You should remove the commented code to improve the readability of your code. The prettier your code format, the more likely someone will read it and answer you.

Comment: change to System.out.println("lowpassvals: " +lowPassVals).get(i);
How do you know the list is empty ?

Comment: @Gordak: 07-02 12:36:47.582  15211-15211/? I/System.out﹕ lowpassvals: [] this is the output. When i add get(i) to lowpassvals in print statement application force stops. If am right i suppose the problem is with sensordata size. It stores only one value. I want to retreive all values of accelerometer and store it in sensorData list. Can you please suggest me what to do. I have added acceldata class that handles accelerometer data in the above question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well the reason is this line

```
 for (int i = 0; accelsum.size() > 10; i++)
```

You will never enter this loop because the condition will never be valid.

Comment: I solved it finally. should change the sensorData arraylist type to AccelData class. and in the acceldata class constructor should pass event of type Sensorevent as the parameter.